# Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at

Tags: regex, linux, perl, recursion

I have a perl script which performs a `pgrep` as follows:

```
use warnings;

my  @instance = `pgrep -fl varnish`;
foreach my $line (@instance) {
my $ip;
        my $port;
        my $pid;
        my $pidfile;
        my $fileconfiguration;
        my $bakendhost;
        my $bakendport;
        my $sharememory;
        my $user;

        chomp $line;
        if ($line =~ m/-T\s+([0-9]+.*)+:(\d+)\s+/) {
           $ip = $1;
           $port = $2;
        }
}
```

However when launch the script am having the following error/warning:

> Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at
>   /home/k.sewnundun/test.pl line 16.
>
> Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at /home/k.sewnundun/test.pl line
>   16.

Please find below the debug:

```
Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:3):
3:      my  @instance = `pgrep -fl varnish`;
  DB<1> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:4):
4:      foreach my $line (@instance) {
  DB<1> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:5):
5:      my $ip;
  DB<1> print $line
3066 /opt/rh/varnish4/root/usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run-daemon/varnishd-toto4.pid -a 0.0.0.0:8080 -f /etc/varnish/etc/toto4/toto4-current.vcl -u varnish4-toto4 -g varnish4-toto4 -l 80M -T 0.0.0.0:38080 -p thread_pool_min=50 -p thread_pool_max=1000 -p thread_pool_timeout=120 -p vcl_dir=/etc/varnish/etc/toto4 -n /home/varnish/toto4/working -s malloc, -S /etc/varnish/etc/toto4/toto4.secret

  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:6):
6:              my $port;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:7):
7:              my $pid;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:8):
8:              my $pidfile;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:9):
9:              my $fileconfiguration;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:10):
10:             my $bakendhost;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:11):
11:             my $bakendport;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:12):
12:             my $sharememory;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:13):
13:             my $user;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:15):
15:             chomp $line;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:16):
16:             if ($line =~ m/-T\s+([0-9]+.*)+:(\d+)\s+/) {
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:17):
17:                $ip = $1;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:18):
18:                $port = $2;
  DB<2> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:5):
5:      my $ip;
  DB<2> print $line
3078 /opt/rh/varnish4/root/usr/sbin/varnishd -P /var/run-daemon/varnishd-toto4.pid -a 0.0.0.0:8080 -f /etc/varnish/etc/toto4/toto4-current.vcl -u varnish4-toto4 -g varnish4-toto4 -l 80M -T 0.0.0.0:38080 -p thread_pool_min=50 -p thread_pool_max=1000 -p thread_pool_timeout=120 -p vcl_dir=/etc/varnish/etc/toto4 -n /home/varnish/toto4/working -s malloc, -S /etc/varnish/etc/toto4/toto4.secret

  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:6):
6:              my $port;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:7):
7:              my $pid;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:8):
8:              my $pidfile;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:9):
9:              my $fileconfiguration;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:10):
10:             my $bakendhost;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:11):
11:             my $bakendport;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:12):
12:             my $sharememory;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:13):
13:             my $user;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:15):
15:             chomp $line;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:16):
16:             if ($line =~ m/-T\s+([0-9]+.*)+:(\d+)\s+/) {
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:17):
17:                $ip = $1;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:18):
18:                $port = $2;
  DB<3> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:5):
5:      my $ip;
  DB<3> print $line
3200 /opt/rh/varnish4/root/usr/bin/varnishncsa -a -n toto4 -w /home/logs/varnish/toto4/access.log -D -P /var/run-daemon/varnishncsa-toto4.pid -F %{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-agent}i"

  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:6):
6:              my $port;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:7):
7:              my $pid;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:8):
8:              my $pidfile;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:9):
9:              my $fileconfiguration;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:10):
10:             my $bakendhost;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:11):
11:             my $bakendport;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:12):
12:             my $sharememory;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:13):
13:             my $user;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:15):
15:             chomp $line;
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:16):
16:             if ($line =~ m/-T\s+([0-9]+.*)+:(\d+)\s+/) {
  DB<4> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:5):
5:      my $ip;
  DB<4> print $line
9803 varnishd -P /var/run-daemon/varnishd-varnish.pid -a 0.0.0.0:80 -f /etc/varnish/varnish.com/varnish.vcl -u varnish-varnish -l 80M -T 127.0.0.1:33080 -w 200,500,120 -n /home/varnish/varnish/working -s malloc,1G -p user varnish-varnish -p acceptor_sleep_decay 0.9 -p acceptor_sleep_incr 0.001 -p acceptor_sleep_max 0.05 -p auto_restart on -p ban_lurker_sleep 0.0 -p between_bytes_timeout 60.0 -p cli_buffer 8192 -p cli_timeout 5 -p clock_skew 10 -p connect_timeout 0.4 -p critbit_cooloff 180.0 -p default_grace 10 -p default_ttl 120 -p diag_bitmap 0x0 -p esi_syntax 0 -p expiry_sleep 1.0 -p fetch_chunksize 128 -p first_byte_timeout 60.0 -p group varnish-varnish -p http_range_support off -p listen_depth 1024 -p log_hashstring off -p log_local_address off -p lru_interval 2 -p max_esi_depth 5 -p max_restarts 4 -p ping_interval 3 -p pipe_timeout 60 -p prefer_ipv6 off -p queue_max 100 -p rush_exponent 3 -p saintmode_threshold 10 -p send_timeout 600 -p sess_timeout 5 -p sess_workspace 16384 -p session_linger 50 -p session_max 10000 -p shm_reclen 255 -p shm_workspace 8192 -p syslog_cli_traffic on -p vcl_trace off -p vcl_dir  -p waiter default

  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:6):
6:              my $port;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:7):
7:              my $pid;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:8):
8:              my $pidfile;
  DB<5> n

main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:9):
9:              my $fileconfiguration;
  DB<5> main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:10):
10:             my $bakendhost;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:11):
11:             my $bakendport;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:12):
12:             my $sharememory;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:13):
13:             my $user;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:15):
15:             chomp $line;
  DB<5> n
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:16):
16:             if ($line =~ m/-T\s+([0-9]+.*)+:(\d+)\s+/) {
  DB<5> n
Complex regular subexpression recursion limit (32766) exceeded at /home/k.sewnundun/test.pl line 16.
 at /home/k.sewnundun/test.pl line 16
main::(/home/k.sewnundun/test.pl:17):
17:                $ip = $1;
  DB<5> q
```

What could be the issue? Thanks

Comment: Using nested quantifiers (as in `([0-9]+.*)+`) is not always a good idea. Note that `.` also matches a digit. Try `m/-T\s+([0-9]+(?:\D+[0-9]+)*\D*):(\d+)\s+/`

Comment: The key phrase here is "Catastrophic backtracking". What we'd really need is example input and expected output. Chances are there's a better way than parsing the output of `pgrep`.

Comment: What @stribizhev said ;) Simplify it to something like `-T\s+([0-9]+[^:]*?):(\d+)\s+` and it should work. Should give you the same result.

Comment: Better yet - don't parse `pgrep` and use something like `Proc::ProcessTable` - from which you can read `cmndline` without having to parse.

Comment: @Kheshav: If you think [`-T\s+(\d+(?:\D+\d+)*\D*):(\d+)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/tB0qR8/4) is working for you, I will post as an answer with explanations. But try a non-regex approach suggested by Sobrique first.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I tried it with `Proc::ProcessTable` as you guys suggested and it worked. Am just wondering why my question was downvoted it shows clearly the things tried out. Never mind, the essential is that the issue is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good sign that your regex is wrong. As has been noted in the comments - you're nesting quantifiers which can lead to problems, especially when matches overlap.. (E.g. `.` also matches `[0-9]`). Several people have mentioned this in the comments - particularly things like `([0-9]+.*)+` - if a match is not found, you end up having to backtrack over the various different combinations of letters/numbers to figure out if a match is present.

You could see this at work if you try something like `use re 'debug'` and notice how your regex starts running a crazy number of steps to process.

But this is something of a moot point when you stop parsing the output of `pgrep`, and instead use something like `Proc::ProcessTable` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper; 
use Proc::ProcessTable; 

my $ps = Proc::ProcessTable -> new; 

foreach my $proc ( grep { $_ -> {cmndline} =~ m/varnish/ } @{$ps->table} ) {
    my %opts = $proc -> {cmndline} =~ m/\-(\w) (\S+)/g;
    print Dumper $proc; 
    print Dumper \%opts;

    my ( $IP, $port ) = split ( ':', $opts{'T'});
}
```